# Query item in inner mongo collection

Tags: mongodb

I have a group collection in my mongo db, where I store group's members in a embedded list:

```
      { _id: 9876,
         name: group138,
         members: [{ login: user1, password: user1pass},
                   { login: user2, password: user2pass}],
         path: '/group1/group13/',
       }
```

(To handle the group hierarchy, I use the Model Tree Structures with materilized paths (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/model-tree-structures-with-materialized-paths/)).

I wanted to find a way to have the couple of users belonging to this group into the same collection to avoid multiple db query (and callback calls).

When a user login, I need to retrieve him and the group he belongs to. I just figured out I cannot query the user with his login and password at the same time:

```
db.groups.find({$and: [{"members.login": "user1pass"}, {"members.password" : "user2pass"}]})
```

returns the record where it should not return it as the password is not the correct one. How can I perform the correct request so it checks the login and the password ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`$elemMatch`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/elemMatch/#op._S_elemMatch) to match multiple properties of a single array element:

```js
db.groups.find({members: {$elemMatch: {login: "user1", password: "user1pass"}}});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just find by the sub-document desired:

```
db.groups.find({members: {login: "user1", password: "user1pass"}})
```