# Cannot query embed list in mongo

Tags: mongodb

I have a group collection in my mongo db, where I store group's members in a embedded list:

```
      { _id: 9876,
         name: group138,
         members: [{ login: user1, password: user1pass},
                   { login: user2, password: user2pass}],
         path: '/group1/group13/',
       }
```

I wanted to find a way to have the couple of users belonging to this group into the same collection to avoid multiple db query (and callback calls).

When a user login, I need to retrieve him and the group he belongs to. I just figured out I cannot query the user with his login and password at the same time:

```
db.groups.find({$and: [{"members.login": "user1pass"}, {"members.password" : "user2pass"}]})
```

returns the record where it should not return it as the password is not the correct one. How can I perform the correct request so it checks the login and the password ?

Comment: Didn't you already ask this question?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17435891/query-item-in-inner-mongo-collection

Comment: Sorry, I had an error submitting my question so I changed it a little bit but both version where published. Could you make it a duplicate ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you query on `"members.login": "user1"`, you're saying "return a group that contains a member with the login `user1`.  Similarly with the second clause, but they're unrelated, so it will return any group that contains a user with the given username and a member with the given password, regardless of whether they're the same member.

What you're looking for is `$elemMatch`:

```
{
  members: 
    {
      $elemMatch:
        {
          login: "user1",
          password: "user1pass"
        }
    }
}
```